# Normal distribution of multiple random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $ X_1,X_2$ and $ X_3$ be independent random variable such that $X_1$ ~ $N(47,10), X_2 $~ $N(55,15)$ and $ X_3$ ~ $N(60,14).$ Then $ P(X_1 + X_2 \geq 2 X_3)$ equals

I know that
$X$ ~ $N(\mu_x ,\sigma^2_x),$
$Y$ ~ $N(\mu_y ,\sigma^2_y)$

$Z = X+Y$ then $Z$ ~ $N( \mu_x +\mu_y $  ,$\ \sigma^2_x  + \sigma^2_y)$

How do we solve this question...

Comment: If $X_3$ is normal, so does $2X_3$. Thus, $X_1+X_2-2X_3$ is normal too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variables are jointly normal because of independence. This implies that $X_1+X_2-2X_3 \sim N(47+55-2(60), 10+15+4(14))$. So you have to find $P(Z\geq 0)$ where $Z \sim N(-18, 81)$. Can you finish?